# Having troubles with @media

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Im just staring with @media css3, and my trouble here is to set responsive, and i dont really get it how to divide this in 2 when the screen goes to 900px

i know its @ media screen (max-width: 900px) {}

but i cant made the code inside work to divide in 2

```css
.row { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
    clear: both; 
    float: left; 
}

.contenido{ 
    width: 985px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: left; 
    clear: both; 
}

.lenovoDescripcion .contenido { 
    width: 978px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: left; 
    clear: both; 
    padding-left: 3px; 
    padding-right: 4px; 
}

.lenovoDescripcion .producto { 
    padding-top: 25px; 
    float: left; 
    padding-bottom: 25px;

}

.lenovoDescripcion .producto img { 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 110px;
}

.lenovoDescripcion .descripcion {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}

.lenovoDescripcion .descripcion h2 { 
    color: #0084b0; 
    font-size: 37px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    height: 43px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 50%;
}

.lenovoDescripcion .descripcion h3 { 
    color: #cc7000; 
    font-size: 29px;
    font-weight: normal; 
    height: auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.lenovoDescripcion .descripcion p { 
    color: #373737; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: bold;
    font-weight: normal; 
    height: auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.lenovoDescripcion .descripcion h4 { 
    color: #c6c6c6; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal; 
    height: auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.lenovoDescripcion .descripcion h5 { 
    color: #0084b0; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal; 
    height: auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 60%;
    margin-top: -35px;
}

.lenovoDescripcion .descripcion li { 
    font-size: 14px; 
    line-height: auto; 
    color: #7d7c7c; 
    height: auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 30%;
    width: 100%;
}

.lenovoDescripcion .descripcion a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #ff4500;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #ff4500;
    margin-left: 60%;
    transition: all linear .15s;
}

.lenovoDescripcion .descripcion a:hover {
    background-color: #b33000;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

strike {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 35%;
    color: #c6c6c6;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    border: 1px dotted #000000;
    width: 30%;
}

footer hr {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row lenovoDescripcion">
<div class="contenido">
    <div class="producto">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/Productos/pc2.png"></a>
        <div class="descripcion">
        <h2>IDEAPAD S400</h2>
        <h5>(59402530)</h5>
        <h4>Precio de lista</h4 >
        <strike>$1,399,000.00</strike>
        <hr>
        <p>Precio con descuento 10%</p>
        <h3>$1,259,100.00</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Fully optimized with recognizable touch gestures for the Windows 8.1 experience</li>
            <li>Added dual-mode functionality to easily convert from a mouse to pointer</li>
            <li>Winner of the Reddot Design Award</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="comprar"><span>DESCUBRE Y COMPRA</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- Producto -->
</div><!-- row -->
```

Comment: add a jsfiddle or codepen link. JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ , Codepen - http://www.codepen.io/. Also, what do you mean by "divide in 2"?

Comment: i cant use js in this work, like split the whole thing in two, make the img stay over the "text". Like if you are scrolling down and you first see the image then the description text

Comment: I never said use js, i'm guessing you didn't open the links? Those two links provide us with a live example of what you're working on, and will allow us to visually understand your code.

Comment: Sorry im just new here, didnt knew what you mean.

Comment: No problem, Franco :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do so with the width attribute and floats. Here is 1 example: http://jsfiddle.net/cUCvY/1/

HTML:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { 
  border : 2px solid #000; 
  overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper div {
   min-height: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
}
#one {
  background-color: gray;
  float:left; 
  margin-right:20px;
  width:140px;
  border-right:2px solid #000;
}
#two { 
  background-color: white;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:10px;
  min-height:170px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   #one { 
    float: none;
    margin-right:0;
    width:auto;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, apriciate it